# Where to place META-INF in Android project

Tags: java, android, serviceloader

I'm writing an app that needs to load dinamically plugins from external libraries.
My first idea was -with very little immagination- to use Java's `ServiceLoader` and googling a little bit I found documentation that states that this kind of action is supported by Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

However I really don't understand where to place my META-INF folder (I'm used to Maven, but I can't use it in this occasion).

Could someone tell me where to place the META-INF folder and what to do to have it working in the usual way?

Stefano

Comment: "I'm writing an app that needs to load dinamically plugins from external libraries" -- that is very difficult to secure. "I found documentation that states that this kind of action is supported by Android" -- technically, that states that `ServiceLoader` exists in Android's SDK. Dianne Hackborn (lead Android engineer) recommends not using it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5761705/115145

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, thank you for the reply. The app I'm developing is for a specific customer and isn't going to be published in GP. The contract of my services isn't going to be exposed to the world and I'll develop plugins on my own, so security is not a real issue in this case. But the app will need many add-ons over time and I wanted an agile way to add them without having to modify the bulk of the code. In addition, with these pugins, it could be customized for other customers. I would just like to know where to place my META-INF, if possible at all. I'll take my risks :) Thanks