# JSR-303 compatible bean validator for Android

Tags: android, bean-validation

Is it really possible that there is no JSR-303 compatible validator for Android around?

Hibernate validator seems not compatible with Android (ClassNotFound Exception) and then... I could not find anything else.

I found Metawidget - but on their Website they say "Metawidget comes with a UI component native to your existing front-end" - I don't need additional UI components.

Here is what I have on the backend:

```
    final String wrongJson = "{\"name\":\"notavalidemail\"}";
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final Project projectFromJson = gson.fromJson(wrongJson, Project.class);

    final ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    final Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    final Set<ConstraintViolation<Project>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(projectFromJson);
    assertNotNull(constraintViolations);

    for (final ConstraintViolation<Project> violation : constraintViolations) {
        logger.debug("Errormessage: {}",violation.getMessage());
    }
```

To avoid a bunch of ifs I want the same on Android - any hints?

[**Update**]
Sorry - it's not ClassNotFound it is

javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at at.mikemitterer.mobiad.android.util.ProjectTest.testWithWrongJsonString(ProjectTest.java:90)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)

[**Update II**]
Yes - hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Alpha1.jar is in my lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Whiche CNF did you exactly get? If it is about `java.beans.Introspector`, this is fixed as of HV 5.1.0.Alpha1 which [doesn't import](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-779) this type anymore and thus should run on Android. If it is about other APIs it would be very interesting to know which ones.

Comment: I'm no expert on Android, but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760607/using-serviceloader-on-android) there are issues with the `ServiceLoader` in this environment (which BV uses to load providers). You might try to explicitly specify your provider like so: `Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure().buidValidatorFactory()`;

Comment: I tried this a few mins ago - same result. I also tried it with ApacheValidationProvider, the same. I think it's a more general problem. Android seems to fail if it should load these Validator classes at runtime.

Comment: Try plugging in your own `ValidationProviderResolver` (via `providerResolver()`) which only returns `HibernateValidator`. This should circumvent the service loader used by the default provider resolver.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question, following my quest for some integration of JSR 343 and Angular.js , which should be more trickier than in your case , as well, with Android you develop with Java.

If you look at [valdr](https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr-bean-validation#features) you will see a framework with model centric approach to validation in angular.js and you will see there a plugin to support JSR 303.
The plugin is composed of several components, you might want to consider "imitating" in Android, for client-server applications and have one "central place" that defines the rules of validation.
For this you will probably need the following:

1. Define the classes at server side to scan for JSR 303 annotations
2. Which classes that your android app are mapped to these java beans
3. A way to get the scanning result and dynmically construct a set of rules
4. Use each rule when a setter on an object that was mapped is being activated.

If this is an android app with no server, then I guess you should try to port the source for JSR 303 to be use with Android